# Canonical reference for "My CSS is not working" questions

Tags: discussion

Is there a canonical answer I can use as a dup target for "my CSS is not working" questions, where the answers are usually using wrong href path, parse errors in the CSS, etc.?

Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694142/css-wont-work-in-webpage).

Comment: Aren't these **typo** questions...and such closeworthy?

Comment: Yes, but they are often also dups in a sense, which would allow them to be closed right away.

Comment: If we close them as typos can't we get them deleted rather than become dupe pointers. I'm not sure a canonical typo Q&A is that useful...but opinions may differ,

Comment: Considering the number of ways CSS can go bad, I'd wager any dupe target would be too broad :)